# Rendering text in pygame causes lag

Tags: python, pygame, lag

I have `write` function in my functions module which looks like this

```
def write(size, writing, color, x,  y):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("corbel", size)
    text = font.render(writing,  True, color)
    D.blit(text, (x, y))
```

I imported this to my main module and created a function as follows in the main module

```
def print_stats():
    write(30, f"Red player's hp {player2.hp}", (200, 50, 50),10, 10)
    write(30, f"Green player's hp {player1.hp}", (50, 200, 50),10, 60)
```

As long as i dont put `print_stats()` in the main loop, the game runs perfectly fine, however, as soon i i try to run this function, it heavily drops FPS. I dont see anything in the code that could cause lag, what am i doing wrong? Thanks

Edit: Dont know if this is relevnet but i forgot to mention that i put `pygame.init()` in all the modules i have imported from as this is my first time using modules and i was unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid to create the font object in every frame.
Create a font dependent on the size before the application loop. e.g:

```py
font30 = pygame.font.SysFont("corbel", 30)
```

```py
def write(font, writing, color, x, y):
    text = font.render(writing,  True, color)
    D.blit(text, (x, y))
```

```py
def print_stats():
    write(font30, f"Red player's hp {player2.hp}", (200, 50, 50), 10, 10)
    write(font30; f"Green player's hp {player1.hp}", (50, 200, 50), 10, 60)
```

---

That doesn't solve the issue, that the text is rendered in every frame. If it is still lags, then you have to render the text surface once, when `player1.hp` respectively `player2.hp` is changed. e.g:

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, color, name):
        self.color = color
        self.name = name
        # [...]

    def ChangeHp(self, val):
        self.hp += val
        self.hptext = font30.render(f"{self.name} player's hp {self.hp}", True, self.color)
```

```py
D.blit(player1.hptext, (10, 60))
```

Comment: But why could it be that when i did the exact same thing in my other project, it worked fine but not this one

Comment: @hippozhipos There can be a lot of reasons, different font, text size, length of the text, framerate, ...